# can you still use php as backend for angularjs2 without nodejs for live application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack

I have to admit that I am rather still new for angularjs2, though, I want to just make sure myself is pursuing the right path before dig in deeper. I wonder is it still possible to use PHP server as the backend for angularjs2? Because I am still not yet understand how webpack works and the idea that serve only things that app will need as if its serving from the server or just only during the build process? Because it seems only work with an index.js file... are we still able to use index.html as compiled code base index file and be able to still use php with js without nodejs in the live application?

Comment: what is the connection between angularjs, PHP and webpack? How are you going to mix webpack and PHP? Yes you can use angularjs of any version with PHP, and no, you can't use webpack with PHP as long as you can't use Java with PHP

Comment: The simple answer is yes. You can have any backend. And if it is rest api it is the best arch for angularjs or angular2 in terms of performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The production build doesnot requires NodeJS as it's just static html/js/css/image files. I am using PHP as my backend server. I have moved to a web service approach with php than mixing PHP with my HTML pages to render data.

Webpack with Node/npm is great tool to modularise the project. [AngularClass Starter Pack](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) is good point to begin with or there are tons of npm projects out there with webpack. Webpack allows easy development/debugging with the browser. For example you can write your config file for development/testing and production separately with webpack. A good example is this one,

```
export const BASE_URL = ('development' === process.env.ENV)
  ?'http://localhost/service/publisher.php'
  :'https://www.myserver.com/publish/index.php';
```

Based on webpack environment, I can switch my php server.

If you are writing a HTML5 app then its a good idea to allow 'option' in your php file for [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Authorization");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

WebPack, and similar module bundlers like browserify and jspm, will bundle your JS application at build time. This means you will have no serverside language dependencies.

You will only need Nodejs on your development machines and build machines. If you use Angular-Universal you will need Nodejs for now. Supposedly support for other languages is coming.

So yes, you can use PHP to host your serverside Rest or json-http service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, Angular2.js is a front framework, and you can do your back with the language of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are no limitations to using a php backend and even with a mySql database with Angular 1 or 2.

However, since services are usually built through json format, it is a bit trickier to store and retrieve data with php from a mySql database. You may need a few lines of extra coding to read & write the json data in a proper format than if you were using, for instance, a mongoDB database on a Node server.

Answer (score 0):

Since someone already mentioned webpack already  ( which is one of my favorite tools ), let me explain more in detail on how it works and hope it helps  ( I'm using Slim PHP as an example )

- Your webpack generate the frontend artifacts ( which is your frontend built file and a meta data file ).  The meta data file ( assets.json ) tells you what file has been generated and where the location is.

For example, the meta file will look something like this

```
`{"vendors":{"js":"assets/vendors.js"},"app":{"js":"assets/f7133dfe501a7dbe8ebd.js"}}`
```

- You can now import the the assets.json to your PHP code, for example, I'm using Twig here.  Of course you need to write some custom logic to parse the json file in your PHP.

[image]